# Running chrome as an alternate user while logged in with different credentials

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, browser, administrator, runas

I am sure I am missing something here. My Chrome runs under a Non Admin a/c so I can't install any extensions . I have an admin  rights a/c and tried to run it using alternate credentials

```
        C:\Windows\system32>C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe
  /savecred /user:IBMClunker\ladmin
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

Chrome pulls up but wont do a think Just get a black slate background and nothing happens. Wont browse any place. So I copied everything the `appdata/local/chrome/user data` folder to the corresponding folder for Ladmin 
Still no luck.
Has any one had luck getting this to work 
Am on W7.

Comment: Why don't you just as an Administrator add the extensions, then run Chrome, as the normal user.  You should not run Chrome as an Administrator for many reasons including for security reasons.  If your running Chrome as an Administrator as another user you might as well just be logged into the Administrator account itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Add the --no-sandbox switch to Chrome**

> runas /user:test /profile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\A
>   pplication\chrome.exe --no-sandbox"

! This will defeat the purpose of running Chrome with restricted account

You can also try to install Chrome for All users at install time.. install Chrome for the specific account you want to use first...

Comment: Works fine, in spite of `You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --no-sandbox` warning. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

When using Windows 10 (and I think 7) you can hold down shift and right-click the application and choose "Run as different user" ... much simpler.